# Converting nvarchar to Date in SQL Server fails when inserting result set into staging table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on this for a couple days trying to understand why my Insert is failing. I have a table with several dates in each record. The data is initially inserted into a "landing" table that is all NVARCHARs. In my Merge Upsert statement I am converting those NVARCHARS into Dates and that produces what I expected and is formatted fine. This result set fails when trying to insert those converted dates into the staging table where the date fields are datatyped as DATES.

Landing table

```
CREATE TABLE [land].[MARA] (
[MATNR] nvarchar(18) NULL,
[ERSDA] nvarchar(12) NULL,
[LAEDA] nvarchar(12) NULL
ON [PRIMARY]
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE);
GO
ALTER TABLE [land].[MARA] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE);
GO
```

This is how the data is stored in landing

```
matnr   ersda   laeda
841058  01.12.1998  23.06.2016
841630  01.12.1998  23.06.2016
842058  01.12.1998  01.06.2016
842085  08.12.1998  23.06.2016
842086  01.12.1998  23.06.2016
```

Staging table

```
CREATE TABLE [stage].[MARA] (
[MATNR] nvarchar(18) NULL,
[ERSDA] date NULL,
[LAEDA] date NULL
ON [PRIMARY]
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE);
GO
ALTER TABLE [stage].[MARA] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE);
GO
```

Select statement

```
SELECT MATNR
  ,REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, ERSDA,101), '.', '/') AS ERSDA
  ,REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, LAEDA,101), '.', '/') AS LAEDA
FROM IBSCM01.land.MARA
```

Executing the above SQL Select produces a result set of formatted dates

```
MATNR   ERSDA   LAEDA
841058  01/12/1998  23/06/2016
841630  01/12/1998  23/06/2016
842058  01/12/1998  01/06/2016
842085  08/12/1998  23/06/2016
```

Adding the Insert clause produces a conversion error

```
INSERT INTO stage.mara
SELECT MATNR
  ,REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, ERSDA,101), '.', '/') AS ERSDA
  ,REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, LAEDA,101), '.', '/') AS LAEDA
FROM IBSCM01.land.MARA

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Executing this Select where the attempt to convert into a date is also throwing the same error.

```
SELECT MATNR
  ,REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, ERSDA,101), '.', '/') AS ERSDA
  ,REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, LAEDA,101), '.', '/') AS LAEDA
FROM IBSCM01.land.MARA
```

What I need is to convert the NVARCHAR date fields into DATES that get Inserted into the stage table and are correct dates.
Any insight is greatly appreciated.
Pat

Comment: Have you tried removing `REPLACE`?  `SELECT CONVERT(DATE,ERSDA,101) ...`

Comment: the problem is with `23.06.2016`.

Comment: @vkp `CONVERT(date, '23.06.2016',103) AS ERSDA`

Comment: @vkp, how is that the problem? Please explain, thanks

Comment: @bjones, I started w/o the replace and it still fails. At least the replace is formatting with slashes and not keeping the dots

Answer (score 1):

You should `convert` it using the [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) `105`, because the dateformat is `dd.mm.yyyy`.

```
SELECT MATNR
,CONVERT(DATE, ERSDA,105) AS ERSDA
,CONVERT(DATE, LAEDA,105) AS LAEDA
FROM IBSCM01.land.MARA
```

The result from the query above, can directly be inserted into the staging table as the datatypes of ERSDA and LAEDA are `DATE`.

Comment: That worked, but how and why. When I tried using 101 style it still failed and I can't find anything in MSDN docs that would indicate why 105 style would work when others failed.

Comment: `101` is for formatting `mm/dd/yyyy` formats. When you use it against `30/06/2016` it fails because `30` is not a valid month.you can use `103` here as well.